# Android Studio No "Import Sample" option in File menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why android studio not showing import sample option in File menu even
if I have downloaded sample projects on my disc?

I have Android Studio 2.2.2 with correct sdk path.

[image]

It's a bug? or ??

[image]

Comment: May be there is no proper internet connection and the Android Studio unable to download samples

Comment: Same here mate. Looks like they took it off

Answer (score 23):

To see this menu option:
File -> New -> Import Sample

you need to turn on:
Settings -> Plugins -> Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio

Comment: This is the answer. It should be checked.

Answer (score 6):

Have you checked "Google Developer Sample" plugin option?
In my case, this option had not been active.

Settings -> Plugins -> Google Developer Samples.

After checking this option, I finally could import sample project.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can import samples ([eg, examples here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sample-Android-Apps)) from Git with File -> New -> Project from version control -> git

Answer (score 0):

You should go to File -> New -> Import Sample.

Comment: look at image. there is no Import Sample

Answer (score -1):

If you search for a example for a specific programming problem, you can now right click on some code e.g. viewpager and choose:

find code sample
.

On the bottom a window appears with example having the same construct. You can now double click and the browser opens and brings you to the git server with the example. From there you can download.

Before you had to browse the examples to find a specific example for your problem, now you can search. This might be an advantage.

I use android studio on mac. Version 2.2.2.

Comment: yes, but it is still not the working example app. just example fragment of code. anyway good tip

Comment: But you could get the whole example online.

Comment: but this is not the problem of this question.

Comment: I think it is related because this " samples browser"  feature is suppose to replace the old mechanism http://tools.android.com/recent .